# running 2 sh files at the same time

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I would like to run 2 sh files at the same time. Can you guys let me know how to do it?

Example: I have `a.sh` file and `b.sh` file and I'd like to run these files at the same time with thread.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious to you, but I wonder what you mean by _with thread_...  As far as I know, each script will get it's own _thread_ at OS level, that is, its own _process id_ and stuff.

Comment: Use GNU `parallel` or `xargs -P`

Answer (score 1):

Run at least one of them in the background. That's a separate *process,* not a separate thread; but you couldn't really run different programs in the same process anyway.

```
./a.sh &
./b.sh
wait
```

This will start up `a.sh` in the background, and run `b.sh` in the foreground. In case that finishes first, we also `wait` for the background process to finish.

There are various issues with output buffering etc which usually confuse newbies. You should probably find a tutorial or FAQ about background jobs before you ask more questions. Here are some Google hits:

- http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ

Answer (score 0):

Hm, if you want them to be run at *the very same exact time*, then that's probably not that simple... I'm not even sure if possible.  The best I can think of is:

```
./a.sh ; ./b.sh
```

They will be executed one after the other, and depending on how long it takes `a.sh` to finish it could be a while.  The other option would be to use a scheduler, like `cron` or `at` - probably there's some *magic* at OS level that allow the two scripts to run at the same time if scheduled that way.

---

**Edit**

From the comments, I have corrected the syntax error caused by `& ;`.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Regarding the other comments, I think that the commands are being ran sequentially, as stated in the bash readme:

> Commands separated by a ; are executed sequentially; the shell  waits 
>   for  each command  to terminate in turn.  The return status is the
>   exit status of the last command executed.

Therefore, `./a.sh ; ./b.sh` will execute `a.sh` first, wait until it finishes, and then run `b.sh`.

Comment: Remove the semicolon; it is a command terminator like ampersand is a command terminator, and you can't have a semicolon on its own (syntax error).

Comment: > `They will be executed one after the other` - (assuming you fix the syntax error @JonathanLeffler points out) no, they will both be sent to the background where they "run at the same time", loosely speaking.